# Prove relationship regarding the scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vector-spaces, vectors, inner-products

For 2 vectors $a,b$ $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and all entries in the vectors are $\geq 1$ is the following relationship true ? :

$\langle a,b \rangle$ $ \leq$ $0.5 \langle a,a \rangle + 0.5 \langle b,b \rangle$

If yes is there a simple way to prove this or a 
geometric intuition behind this relationship ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $$\|a-b\|^2=\langle a-b,a-b \rangle \ge 0.$$

Can you simplify the expression $\langle a-b,a-b \rangle$ in some way? Can you get the inequality you are asking about from this?

> $$\langle a-b,a-b \rangle = \langle a,a \rangle - 2\langle a,b \rangle + \langle b,b \rangle \ge 0$$
>  
>  $$\langle a,a \rangle + \langle b,b \rangle \ge 2\langle a,b \rangle $$

---

You may also have a look how this relates to [law of cosines](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Cosine_Formula_for_Dot_Product).

Comment: No I don't get any further with this information sorry

Comment: I have added more detailed explanation.